# Strange result when trying to add a char after an integer and then print the result

Tags: java, printing, floating-point, char

I'm trying to create a simple calculator voor Ohm's law. 
So the idea is that you can fill in 2 variables and then it will calculate the third variable.

When I was creating this program, I found a little problem and I don't understand how it happens and unfortunately I'm not able to find the answer.

I tried to print a String where the complete calculation is shown. So the 2 variables the user filled in and the answer. After the variable for Ohm ('R' in this example) the correct symbol should be printed aswell.

As shown in the example below, the only way I can add the symbol after the variable is by first adding an empty string(""). Otherwise the unicode wil be added to the variable?!

I've made a quick example to show my problem:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float R = 2.54f;
        float U = 4.00f;
        float I = R / U;
        char ohm = '\u2126';
        System.out.println(R + "" + ohm + " (R) / " + U + "V (U) = " + I + "A (I)");
        System.out.println(R + ohm + " (R) / " + U + "V (U) = " + I + "A (I)");
    }
}
```

Result in console:

2.54Ω (R) / 4.0V (U) = 0.635A (I)

8488.54 (R) / 4.0V (U) = 0.635A (I)

As you can see, the second print doesn't show the Ohm symbol, but adds a value to the variable 'R'. Hopefully I've made my question clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`R + ohm` performs a numeric addition of a `float` and a `char` (which is an integral type). Therefore you see a `float` result instead of the String concatenation you expect. The `float` result you see is `8486 + 2.54` (since `8486` is the decimal value of the hexadecimal number `2126`).

In your first `println` statement you avoid that by concatenating a `String` ("") to the `float`, which results in a `String`. Then the Ohm `char` is concatenated to that `String`.

You can also begin with the empty `String` to get the desired output:

```
System.out.println("" + R + ohm + " (R) / " + U + "V (U) = " + I + "A (I)");
```

Comment: Thanks Eran, very clear answer. Now I understand the problem and I know more about the concatenation process and how the result 8488.54 occurred.